# How to add unique constraint in postgres on two columns where value of one column is `true`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in which I need unique `EmpId`. Duplicate is when there are more than one entry with same `EmpId` where `isDeleted = false`

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    id serial primary key,
    EmpId character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    EmpName character varying(15),
    isDeleted boolean,

    unique (EmpId , isDeleted )//where isDeleted is false
)
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done using a check constraint, because you need to check multiple rows and columns.  Why do you think you need this to implement soft delete?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need this for softdelete

Comment: What I'm saying is that a DB check alone doesn't guarantee that your business logic is sound.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know. I will be placing validations and everything but I wanted to this DB check to be 100% sure that no duplicate entries make it to the database if i miss anything by mistake in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no constraint of that kind, but you can create a partial unique index (unique constraints are implemented with unique indexes under the hood):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON sometable (empid) WHERE NOT isdeleted;
```

That will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Dear Laurenz, great work. it just need little bit modification for mssql as  (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [const_name] ON [sometable] (empid) WHERE NOT isdeleted;)

Comment: But this question is not about Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: with this, if i have EmpId 'A' with isDeleted=false in the database. i can still insert new record with EmpId='A' which is what the op want to avoid

Comment: Insted of MSSQL, MySQL and etc also demands name of constrants.

Comment: @JeffryEvan That's a possible interpretation of the question, yes. I had assumed that OP wants no constraints if `isdeleted` is `TRUE`. OP will tell us.

Comment: @MDanish: `where not isdeleted` wouldn't work on SQL Server to begin with as it does not have a true boolean data type.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry for replying late, I got caught up with something. Yes you got my question just right. I do not want rows that have isdeleted=true to be taken into consideration for uniqueness.

Answer (score -2):

i think for this, you can't use UNIQUE constraint but need to create a custom function

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_empID(varchar, boolean) RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS 
// your implementation
```

then use it with CHECK constraint

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    id serial primary key,
    EmpId character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    EmpName character varying(15),
    isDeleted boolean,

    CONSTRAINT ck_active_emp CHECK (check_empID(EmpId, isDeleted))
)
```

since the function will use the table, then you can create the table without the constraint so you can create and test your function. then alter the table to add the constraint later

Comment: That will not work very well. The function will have to access other rows in the table, and if two inserts are running concurrently, they cannot see each other's effects. Moreover, check constraints should not depend on anything but the current row, else you might get surprises during dump/restore (probably not in this special case). Such a function should be `IMMUTABLE` by rights (which yours could not be).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe havent try it myself but i guess you are right, maybe before insert trigger can be used for this scenario if OP want to do database level checking, otherwise application level checking will do the job. i prefer to make EmpID as PK (from the current design, its a manual input, not an auto increment ID) and in case resigned employee join the company again then they will get new employee ID (not reactivate the old ID to keep the history)

Comment: It won't make a difference for visibility whether it is a `BEFORE` or `AFTER` trigger. I agree with your other comments.